# How to filter windows event viewer by application name?(looking for my c#/wpf crashes)

Tags: .net, logging, crash, stack-trace, event-log

It looks like many of my application crashes are logged in the windows event viewer with the actual exception(awesome).

Unfortunately I can't find a way to filter by application, looking at the xml it looks like the application name isn't in its own tag for some reason(Its at the start Event->Data->"Application: MyAppName Framework Verrsion v4.0........*")?

What would be the custom xml to filter by application name?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: no i'm not workin w/ windows/.net anymore

Answer (score 2):

In the latest iteration of Windows 10, it's not still possible to filter out by application name from the event viewer by filter. One approach is to find the first occurrence of the faulting application and use the event ID to filter the results. But that only covers one event type.

With XML, create a custom view to filter an application (Edge in this case):

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">
    *[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]] and *[EventData[Data and (Data='MicrosoftEdge')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

This filters through warnings, errors, and criticals. Once created, The custom views are accessed on the left tree-view pane.